# What is difference between FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS and htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php, filter, htmlspecialchars

I have a textarea which will be available to users as comment box so any sort of inputs are acceptable but that should be accepted only as text and not code. Basically I want to protect my database. I don't want to strip tags or such thing, I just want that if any users even inputs a code that should be stored in database as text and shouldn't be causing any harm to database. So came across these two `php` functions now I am not sure which one ofthese I should use as I am not able to understand difference in them.

Comment: This is only related to html output. To insert safely in your database, you should use a prepared statement. Then you don't have to clean / encode your data separately.

Comment: @jeroen oh thanks already using that, so u mean these functions are mere for browsers ? and if m not using prepared statements, using these functions will not help sanitizing data to be stored in db?

Comment: Exactly, this does nothing for the database.

Answer (score 1):

According to official PHP docs, `htmlspecialchars()` and `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` *should* be equivalent:

> Equivalent to calling htmlspecialchars() with ENT_QUOTES set. Encoding quotes can be disabled by setting FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES. Like htmlspecialchars(), this filter is aware of the default_charset and if a sequence of bytes is detected that makes up an invalid character in the current character set then the entire string is rejected resulting in a 0-length string. When using this filter as a default filter, see the warning below about setting the default flags to 0.

Taken from here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Going from here, I think it would be a matter of personal preference as to which function you prefer more.

Answer (score 0):

From this : http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/275315-htmlspecialchars-vs-filter-sanitize-special-chars/

> They are quite similar yes, but as the PHP manual states
>   htmlspecialchars escapes a bit more than just
>   FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS.
>
> That brings us to the next point, SQL injection prevention. As stated
>   htmlspecialchars is for escaping output to a HTML-parser, not a
>   database engine. The DB engine doesn't understand HTML, and doesn't
>   care about it either. What it does understand, is SQL queries. SQL
>   queries and HTML use quite different meta-characters, with only a few
>   in common: Quotes being the most obvious, and even that is somewhat
>   conditional for HTML. However, due to the other meta-characters (which
>   HTML does not share) using HTML escaping methods for SQL queries will
>   not protect you. Those meta-characters will go through
>   htmlspecialchars unscathed, and thus be able to cause SQL injections.
>
> Same the other way around, if you use SQL escaping methods to escape
>   output going to a browser. It will not escape the < and > signs,
>   meaning an attacker can easily perform HTML injection attacks (XSS
>   etc). Not only that, but you'll suddenly have a lot of slashes in
>   places where there shouldn't be any. Which is quite annoying, at best.
>
> This is why it's so important to know, and use, the proper method for
>   the third party system you're sending the data to. If you don't, you
>   are still vulnerable

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS`, not `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`.